# Access a child key:value for a user in Firebase - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user with they typical Name and Email Fields. There is another field that has a child with another user's UID and Bool Value.

I would like to access that user UID.

Database

--Firstname

--Lastname

--studentSession1List

----UID:True

```
struct User {


var uid: String
var firstName: String
var lastName: String
var email: String?
var password: String?
var username: String?
var pushToken: String?
var studentSession1List: [String: Any]?
var studentSession2List: [String: Any]?
var hasUsername: Bool = false

init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {

    self.uid = uid
    self.firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
    self.lastName = dictionary["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""
    self.password = dictionary["password"] as? String ?? ""
    self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
    self.pushToken = dictionary["pushToken"] as? String ?? ""
    self.studentSession1List = dictionary["studentSession1List"] as? [String: Any] ?? ""
    self.studentSession2List = dictionary["studentSession2List"] as? [String: Any] ?? ""
}}

var filteredUsers = [User]()
var users = [User]()
fileprivate func fetchUsers() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("studentUsers")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in

            if key == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                return
            }

            guard let userDictionary = value as? [String : Any] else { return }

            let user = User(uid: key, dictionary: userDictionary)
            self.users.append(user)


        })

        self.users.sort(by: { (u1, u2) -> Bool in

            return u1.lastName.compare(u2.lastName) == .orderedAscending
        })

        self.filteredUsers = self.users
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        print(self.filteredUsers)

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch users in search", err)
    }
}
```

My user array is giving me a no UID:True key:values for the studentSession1List.

Comment: In this statement:  `guard let userDictionary = value as? [String : Any] else { return }` is value a dictionary? , please check by adding this statement: `print(value)` after the above  statement

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Added the print and I do get this as an output. studentSession1List =     {
        oqInIi3UUiMlbfaneJrAAWnVWZd2 = 1;
    };   This is along with the first, last, and email.  So, I am wondering how to access this in the User Struct?  I would like to set the found UID as a variable to then look up another user.

Comment: I think instead of `self.studentSession1List = dictionary["studentSession1List"] as? [String: Any] ?? ""` , you should write this: `self.studentSession1List = dictionary["studentSession1List"] as? [String: Any]`

Comment: That worked thanks.